# Graph export issue

Tags: gephi

I have some issue regarding Gephi file export (graph of 39 nodes and 38 edges). When exporting (any format, png/pdf/svg) this is the result:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the preview tab, try toggling Edges "Rescale Weight". Select "Refresh" after each change for it to take effect.  Reducing your Edge "Thickness" in that section might also work for you.

You may want to double-check that you have a recent version, I think preview has had some enhancements and fixes recently. But I do agree that generally it is not always intuitive how to use the preview feature.